# Hazard ratio and skewness

Tags: distributions, survival, skewness, hazard

Suppose the distribution $F$ is absolutely continuous. Is there a way to compare (i) the monotonocity of the hazard ratio (i.e., strictly decreasing/increasing); (ii) the skewness of the distribution (i.e., positive or negative); and (iii) the concavity or convexity of the survival function.

I have the intuition that a decreasing hazard ratio implies a concave survival function, which, in turn, implies a positive skewness, but I do not have a formal proof.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is a little off here, but you are getting close to the true situation.  It is possible to show that a decreasing hazard rate implies a convex log-survival function, and the convexity of the survival function depends partly on the rate-of-change of the hazard function, but also on the actual hazard value.  Below I will show how you can derive relevant results for the relationship between a decreasing hazard function and the survival function.  I have not included any analysis of the skewness, since this has a complicated relationship to the hazard function.

---

The CDF $F$ can be written in terms of the hazard function $h$ as:

$$F(t) = 1 - \exp \bigg( - \int \limits_0^t h(r) \ dr \bigg),$$

so the log-survival function is:

$$\log S(t) = \log (1-F(t)) = - \int \limits_0^t h(r) \ dr.$$

Consequently, applying [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) we have:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt} \log S(t) &= - h(t), \\[6pt]
\frac{d^2}{dt^2} \log S(t) &= - \frac{dh}{dt}(t). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

We then have:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d^2 S}{dt^2}(t) 
&= S(t) \cdot \frac{d^2}{dt^2} \log S(t) + \frac{1}{S(t)} \bigg( \frac{dS}{dt}(t) \bigg)^2 \\[6pt]
&= S(t) \Bigg[ \frac{d^2}{dt^2} \log S(t) + \bigg( \frac{1}{S(t)} \frac{dS}{dt}(t) \bigg)^2 \Bigg] \\[6pt]
&= S(t) \Bigg[ \frac{d^2}{dt^2} \log S(t) + \bigg( \frac{d}{dt} \log S(t) \bigg)^2 \Bigg] \\[6pt]
&= - S(t) \Bigg[ \frac{dh}{dt}(t) - h(t)^2 \Bigg]. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Both the survival function and the log-survival function are non-increasing functions, which is a standard property that does not require any assumptions.  As you can see, if $h$ is decreasing then the second derivative of the log-survival function must be positive, which means that the log-survival function is convex.  As to the survival function, it will be concave at any point where the rate-of-change of the hazard function is larger in magnitude than the square of the hazard rate (and it will be convex at any point where the rate-of-change of the hazard function is smaller in magnitude than the square of the hazard rate).

If you are willing to assume that the hazard rate is decreasing, and the magnitude of the rate-of-change is non-decreasing then there will be a certain point at which the rate-of-change becomes larger in magnitude than the square of the hazard rate and it will never thereafter drop below that value.  This would mean that the survival function *becomes concave* at a certain point and then remains concave thereafter.